# Books to start learning big data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, pentaho, bigdata

I would like to start learning about the big data technologies. I want to work in this area in the future. Does anyone know good books to start learning about it? Hadoop, HBase.

Beginner -
intermediate -
advanced -

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Asking about book recommendations are generally not considered good question material. You can read more about that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations), so I'm voting to close this question based on that.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson it is quite surprising that this is closed , whereas this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list is not.

Answer (score 12):

I think a good start for beginner will be the [Big Data course](https://www.coursera.org/course/bigdata) from Coursera

For example I've learnt the basics of MapReduce techonlology.

Answer (score 12):

How about [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do), from O'Reilly Media. It covers everything to do with Hadoop, MapReduce, HDFS and more.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the `Cloudera` resources I'd highly recommend you the reference books from [O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/) :

- Hadoop: The Definitive Guide
- Programming Pig
- Programming Hive
- HBase: The Definitive Guide

You might also check it's [data science kit](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/get/data-science-kit.do) as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to learn machine learning alongside the technology part https://www.coursera.org/course/ml. Learning statistics is also very important.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in Hive and Pig there are also more specialised books about these technologies:

- [Programming Hive](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023555.do)
- [Programming Pig](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/index.html)